# how to manually invoke these events? ngOnInit not getting fired for the component injected using the component factory resolver ?

Tags: angular, angular6

**ngOnInit** not getting fired for the component injected using the component factory resolver

```js
@ViewChild('target', {
  read: ViewContainerRef
}) target;
@Input() step;
@Input() stepinfo;

cmpRef: ComponentRef < any > ;
private isViewInitialized: boolean = false;

constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private compiler: Compiler,
    private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}

updateComponent() {
  if (!this.isViewInitialized) {
    return;
  }
  if (this.cmpRef) {
    this.cmpRef.destroy();
  }
  let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.step);
  this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory)
  this.cmpRef.instance.data = this.stepinfo;
  // (<InjectComponent>componentRef.instance).data = this.step;
  // this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

> after few reading i came to know in these case we need to
>   manually invoke these events. am struggling in how to do that

Comment: You've spelt `ngOnInit` incorrectly in 2 places in this question. Are you sure you've not just got a code typo ? Also, where is the component with the `ngOnInit` in it ?

Comment: Sorry thats just a typo. i have corrected that thanks for the catch.

Comment: Check this stack blitz reference - https://stackblitz.com/angular/kbbqkdkrdva?file=src%2Fapp%2Fad-banner.component.ts

Comment: with this approch its working fine for mee too. the problem comes with this code

Comment: Can you put in the entire code. The other components as well. May be create a stackblitz, so that we can see what is going wrong

Comment: I believe that when you are creating the components this way you have to manually trigger the life cycle methods on your own.

Comment: yes Daniel, i also read about that am struggling in how to do that? can any one help me on that

Comment: After you set the instance data, you'll have to manually call the `ngOnInit` method like `this.cmpRef.instance.ngOnInit();`

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel that worked for me. Can you post this as an answer so that somebody else can get benefited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you manually create components using the `ComponentFactoryResolver`, you will have to manually call the Angular life cycle events that you are using on them.

Since these methods are public on your component, you can call them like a normal method. In this case, we are wanting to call the `OnInit` life cycle event, so it would be like the following:

```js
updateComponent() {
  if (!this.isViewInitialized) {
    return;
  }

  if (this.cmpRef) {
    this.cmpRef.destroy();
  }

  let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.step);
  this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory)
  this.cmpRef.instance.data = this.stepinfo;

  this.cmpRef.instance.ngOnInit(); // <-- this is where the life cycle event is ran
}
```